# UITableView reloadData() does not refresh displayed cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have

```
class StationViewController : 
    UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  @IBOutlet var stationTableView: UITableView!
```

When update the data in my data source and do

```
stationTableView.reloadData()
```

this is not immediately visible on the screen. If I scroll, tilt or do anything else which forces a repaint of the screen the updated cells are visible. I can confirm that the
UITableView did do the update by calling

```
println("\(stationTableView.visibleCells())")
```

which prints the expected cells.

The rest of the setup is a `UINavigationController` which has my `StationViewController`as a relationship. The IBOutlet for the `stationViewController` is connected to the `UITableView` in the storyboard file.

I seem to need a "repaint" of the screen to make my update immediately visible. How do I do that?

Comment: Most probably you're calling `stationTableView.reloadData()` not from a main thread.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to Artem, I figured out I need to call reloadData() on the main thread. This is how I solved that:

```
func refreshUI() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.stationTableView.reloadData()
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this and got "Expected expression" build error. What is dispatch_async() ?

Comment: thanks, that helps!
here's the code for Swift 3
`func refreshUI() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }`