# UITableView reloadData() using lots of power calling from cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

My UITableView will only show all of the fully loaded contents in the cells if I follow the advice of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958282/uitableview-reloaddata-does-not-refresh-displayed-cells) and call reloadData() in the main thread with DispatchQueue. I'm doing this in tableView cellForRowAt because it wasn't fully loading the values from my array into all of the cells otherwise. Now it's constantly reloading and is obviously very energy intensive. This makes it harder to scroll in the Table View, which makes sense.

How can I prevent this ridiculous use of energy while still loading the data into the cells as I need?

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell? =
        charitiesSupportedTable?.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SupportedCell")
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle,
                               reuseIdentifier: "abc")
    }


        if(indexPath.row <= moneyRaisedOfPrevPostsArray.count-1){
            cell?.textLabel?.text = charOfPrevPostsArray[indexPath.row]
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = moneyRaisedOfPrevPostsArray[indexPath.row]
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.charitiesSupportedTable.reloadData()
        }

    return cell!
}
```

Here's my viewDidLoad where I create the array

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser!.email
    var email1 = userEmail?.replacingOccurrences(of: "@", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)
    email1 = email1?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)



    charitiesSupportedTable.delegate = self
    charitiesSupportedTable.dataSource = self

    charitiesSupportedTable.isScrollEnabled = false

    reff = Database.database().reference().child("Posts")

    let userRef1 =  reff?.queryOrdered(byChild: "user").queryEqual(toValue : email1)

    userRef1?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            let value = snap.value
            let valueAsDict = value as! NSDictionary


            charityOfPrevPosts = valueAsDict.value(forKey: "charity") as! String
            viewCountOfPrevPosts = valueAsDict.value(forKey: "viewCount") as! String // times .006
            moneyRaisedPrevPosts  = Double(viewCountOfPrevPosts)! * 0.006

            charOfPrevPostsArray.append(charityOfPrevPosts)
            moneyRaisedOfPrevPostsArray.append(String(moneyRaisedPrevPosts))



        }

        charOfPrevPostsArray.reverse()
        moneyRaisedOfPrevPostsArray.reverse()



    }
    )
    moneyRaisedOfPrevPostsArray.removeAll()
    charOfPrevPostsArray.removeAll()




    reff = Database.database().reference().child("UsersViews").child(email1!).child("totalMoneyRaised")
    reff?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var totalMoney = snapshot.value as! Double

        self.totalMoneyLabel.text = String(format: "$%.02f", totalMoney)
    })

    // don't know if this part is relevant but I do return charitiesCount + 2 in numberOfRowsInSection
    reff = Database.database().reference()
    databaseHandle = reff?.child("UsersViews").child(email1!).child("charitiesSupported").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let myDictionary11 = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        // Adds brands and charities to myData array
        for value in (myDictionary11?.allValues)! {
            self.myCharities.append(value as! String)
        }
        charitiesCount = self.myCharities.count

    })


}
```

Comment: This will continuously reload your cell. you should not call it at cellforRow. why not have a function that you explicitly call to reload the tableview?

Comment: @Joshua I call it at cellForRow because then I know it will certainly fill all the cells I need from the arrays. I don't know how to achieve the same thing with a function

Comment: what I mean is after populating your Data source in your case moneyRaisedOfPrevPostsArray. then you call your reloadData. Dont do it at the same space wherein you are displaying a cell. It can be on your func didUpdateArrayThing () { DispatchQueue.main.async {charitiesSupportedTable.reloadData()} something like that

Comment: @Joshua I populate the data source in viewDidLoad and if I call the DispatchQueue after I populate it in the same function it doesn't load all of the values from the array into the cells

Comment: why don't you reload your cells in ViewWillAppear() method?
this will make your code light

Comment: What you are doing here is definitely wrong and will lead to your table view continuously reloading which is why it is causing problems scrolling.  No matter what setup you have this is wrong.  If you share more details of how you are loading the data then we can see what you should be doing instead.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth updated, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure the entire viewDidLoad code is correct but to solve your question you need to reload the table once you have populated the arrays so call `self.charitiesSupportedTable.reloadData()` after the arrays are filled (and reversed) not in the cellForRowAt.

Comment: @NitinGohel please don't shout and try to be a bit more constructive.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth right, I tried that and it doesn't lose all of the array into the cells

Comment: You just do your work instead of advice to me @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: @NitinGohel fair enough someone appears to be a bit touchy this morning.  Although we are on a site designed to offer help and advice.  Beside it's the weekend so I don't have to do work and am just trying to help people out.

Comment: @Nate I think you have a bigger problem with the code in viewDidLoad.  Did you try dispatching the reload of the table view onto the main queue?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth by using DispatchQueue.async after I reverse the arrays in viewDidLoad, yes. I only get 2 out of the 5 desired values in the array to show in the table view

Comment: @Nate to dispatch onto the main queue you should use DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth sorry yes that's what I meant!

Comment: Where did you put it in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth immediately after I reverse the arrays

Comment: If your table also relies on `self.myCharities.count` then you might want to try the doing the same after that is set (I think it's towards the end of viewDidLoad)

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth that fixed it!! I reloaded it in this for loop: for value in (myDictionary11?.allValues)! {}. I guess that just made it reload it enough times

Comment: I think you might be able to do that just once after that for loop has finished.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth yes, you're right!

Comment: Cool the trick is to always call the reloadData once you have finished doing anything that affects the data the table is based upon.  Glad it's working for you now.